# MySQL, Max doesnt appear to be working?

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing data and one of the fields is 'class'

When i do:

```
select* from cvs where `Player ID` = <a_number>
```

i get data containing class numbers from 1 to 10

If i then do

```
select max(`Class`) from cvs where `Player ID` = <a_number>
```

it returns 9 and not 10?

I deleted the 10th class data and it still returned 9, i deleted the 9th class data and it returned 8

Class is a varchar(50)

What is happening???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Class field is only populated with integers, try:

```
select max(cast(Class as UNSIGNED)) 
from cvs 
where `Player ID` = <a_number>
```

MySQL is doing an alphanumeric sort rather than numeric, since it is a varchar. When it compares the first characters, `'9'` is greater than `'1'`, so that gets sorted after `'10'`.

Ideally, if the data is numeric, then it should be stored using the appropriate numeric type, rather than varchar. This will also avoid problems where a query that works fine now stops working in the future just because a single non-integer value was inserted in the `Class` column.

Answer (score 1):

its not an int so its alphabetizing them. and 9>1.

either:

```
cast(variable as int)
```

or

```
convert(int, variable)
```